# Saving image names in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, image-manipulation

Currently i have system that's do resizing and creating as many images as needed and storing them on web servers file system. Also i make and entry in database of image basename in mysql.
For example i upload 5 images the basename would be 372FDSC and then it will add _0, _1 etc. to each image in filesystem so it makes image look like 372FDSC_0.jpeg and so forth.

So where is my problem? It's that i cannot delete or upload new images since i don't know image name in code.

I wonder is there is some better solution to save image names for article? Like mysql row that holds all names (372FDSC_0.jpgeg;372FDSC_01.jpeg etc.) So when i delete or upload new ones i know what filename i can use.

I hope this all makes some sense to anyone if not please say and i'll add required details.

Comment: Every answer here is not what i was looking for but that's probably because my poor question. So i pick one that helped me a bit to rewrite my image workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a timestamp at the end of the image name, so you're sure it's unique.

```
$new_name = $basename . "_" . time() . $extension;
```

Comment: Btw after some time banging this crap script i got i realized that time() function is not guaranteed unique value. Since my script is uber fast i get like all images with same timestamp.
 So i'll probably generate my own 12 symbol string for each image name.

Comment: Oh and also if you generate same way name for thumbnails and other images the names will be off.

Comment: You could use a sleep() after each image, so the timestamp will be changed. To get the same timestamp for thumbnail and image, you should keep the time stamp in a variable. Like $time = time() so the timestamp will be captured.

Answer (score 1):

You could use timestamp as stated above or you could also give your images descriptive names based on what the image contains instead of the 372FDSC naming.

Answer (score 1):

Have 3 columns in your database table titled 'basename', 'no of images', 'article name'.
Now make a loop to get all the images.
eg if you have 5 images in your article 'abc'. Then you will use

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
   $images[]=$basename.$imageno;
```

keeping in mind that $basename is the basename retrieved from database and same applies to $imageno.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your **article id field to rename images**.  For example, if your article id is 237, the images will be 237_1.jpg, 237_2.jpg etc.

In that case, you will not need to store image name in db also.